# Convert Date(JS) object to TimeStamp(firestore) in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I've got a date object in Google App Script which I want to import to firestore as a timestamp object, but it doesn't work when I do it directly.

This stores an empty map in firestore:

```
data.date = new Date();
```

I get this in firestore:

[image: I get this]

But I want this:

[image]

This is my full code:

```
function uploadData() {
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
   var dataSR = 2; 
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

  // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
       var data = {};

       var date = sourceData[i][0]; //this is the date object
       data.date = new Date(); //Want to convert this date to timestamp object for firestore
       data.title = sourceData[i][1];

       firestore.createDocument("collection", data);
     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this [bug has been fixed](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues/86) in the latest version.